# C program not giving prime numbers

Tags: c, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse in Ubuntu Mate. When I compile the following program, it compiles it without giving any errors. It does not show any warnings or errors in the Eclipse text editor window, but when I compile it, it says "errors exist in required project. Continue launch?".

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,b,num,div,exi;
printf("this program find out the prime numbers\nnow enter the number until you want to find prime numbers here:- ");
scanf("%d",&b);


for(num=1;num<=b;num++)
{
  for(div=2;div<=(num/2);div++)
  {
    a=num%div;
    if(a!=0)
    {
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d \n",num);
      break;
    }
  }
}



printf("enter any digit to exit");
scanf("%d",&exi);
printf("you entered the %d,thus good bye",exi);
}
```

and when I hit the "yes" button it gives me the following output:

```
this program find out the prime numbers
now enter the number until you want to find prime numbers here:- 20
4 
6 
8 
9 
10 
12 
14 
15 
16 
18 
20 
enter any digit to exit7
you entered the 7,thus good bye
```

This is not the output I want, but Eclipse doesn't tell me what the error in my program is so that I can fix it. Also, can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: An error in the project can be any thing - not necessarily related to your code. It compiles fine for me.

Comment: @ kabanus why eclipse is not showing it to me?

Comment: @kabanus and what is the error exactly?

Comment: There is no error in your code (the fact that it does not find primes is a bug, not a syntax error). The project thing is probably unrelated. Do you want to change your question to why is your program outputting all multiples of 2 up to input number? If so please change it, and say what you actually want to do.

Comment: "Doctor, my stomache hurts. What can it be?" - **You** get the error, so **you** do know what the error is exactly! Crystall balls are out today.

Comment: @kabanus I will edit it

Comment: No one is making fun of you, but your code has nothing to do with prime numbers.

Comment: @linuxman Olaf is pointing out the fact that you mention there is something "wrong" in your code but never actually tell us what in your opinion the problem might be.

Comment: @Fredrik  how ? can you please tell me?

Comment: I can give you a hint. A prime number is only divisible by 1 and itself.

Comment: The output you get is the output you programmed.  You are testing for compositeness (the opposite of primality), and your code correctly prints the composite numbers between 2 and 20.  You need to revise the logic so it detects when a number is prime. You can stop the inner loop when `div * div > num`.  At numbers under 100, this doesn't matter much; if you encroach on 1,000,000, then it makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @Olaf is a bit harsh, but he has a point - this question is written badly, it's unclear what you intended to do. If `div` does not divide `num` you print it - this maybe useful for your debug, but we don't know what you expected. Write exactly what you expected for a given output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse can **not** tell you that your program doesn't work. It can only tell you if your code can't be compiled into a program.

Your code can compile so eclipse will not give any errors.

But your program doesn't work because as it doesn't print the primes.

Let's look at your inner-loop:

```
  for(div=2;div<=(num/2);div++) // Here you want to test if num can be divided
                                // by 2 or 3 or 4 or .....
                                // That is fine
  {
    a=num%div;                  // So here you do the check, i.e. you calculate
                                // the reminder
    if(a!=0)
    {
      // Reminder is non-zero. That will happen for e.g. 5%2 (which is 1)
      // So you continue the loop if num is a prime candidate
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      // Reminder is zero. That will happen for e.g. 4%2
      // So you print the numbers that are NOT primes and stop the loop
      printf("%d \n",num);
      break;
    }
  }
```

So in the end, your program does the opposite of what you want. It prints all the non-primes and ignores the primes.

So toggle is around and don't print until you have checked all values! Therefore - use a flag in the inner loop and print in the outer loop.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,num,div,exi;
   printf("this program find out the prime numbers\nnow enter the number until you want to find prime numbers here:- ");
   scanf("%d",&b);


    for(num=2;num<=b;num++)  // Start from 2
    {
        int flag = 1; // Assume prime
        for(div=2;div<=(num/2);div++)
        {
            a=num%div;
            if(a==0)
            {
                flag = 0;  // No - not a prime
                break;
            }
       }
       if (flag) // Was it a prime?
       {
            printf("%d \n",num);  // Yes
       }
     }



      printf("enter any digit to exit");
      scanf("%d",&exi);
      printf("you entered the %d,thus good bye",exi);
  }
```

Notice: I tried to keep the code in this answer similar to the code in the question. However, the code can be performance improved in several ways. Just search here on SO for "prime" and you'll find more optimal solutions.

Comment: but please can you tell me what is wrong in my program? i am new to programming.